# Выполнение функции по расписанию

Tags: c#, таймер, asp.net-mvc, функции

Как лучше воспользоваться архитектурой `ASP.NET MVC 3`, чтобы впихнуть туда функцию с таймером, каждые сутки, в 03:00 например, делающую некоторые действия с базой?

Answer (score 4):

Обязательно функция с таймером? Если нет то наверное лучше сделать какие-то действия с бд настроив джоб в самой бд. Или написать утилиту и закинуть ее в scheduler. Еще как вариант можно сделать какой-нибудь windows service.

Comment: Вариант с джобой самое то! Спасибо, почему-то в голове даже и не всплыло. Про scheduler можно поподробнее? Никогда не сталкивался с этим.

Comment: Если кратко - указывается исполняемый файл (если нужны указываются параметры) и настраивается расписание. Где его найти тут - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows7/schedule-a-task.